# Rake Migrate will not work on developement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm following along with some tutorials and they are teaching how to create and run migrations. All has been working so far but I have run in to a problem. But now when i have come back to it the migration will not work in the development database. I used  rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production to see if my migrations work and on that database it can go through all the migrations and back down again with no problems are errors but when I run  rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development it pauses for a few seconds then returns me to the console awaiting a command. No errors are shown or nothing is returned to show what it has done and when checking the DB nothing has changed. What can this be?

Answer (score 0):

Use --trace

```
rake db:migrate --trace
```

Show your database.yml file please.

Comment: ryaz is right, working in prod, failing in development, almost certainly means different connection strings in database.yml